# "Range($T$) is dense if and only if Ker($T^*$) $=\{0\}$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear bounded operator from Hilbert space $X$ to $X$.
I want to show that

"Range($T$) is dense if and only if Ker($T^*$) $=\{0\}$"

How can I show this?

Comment: Use the fact that a subspace is dense iff its orthogonal is trivial.

Comment: For any $S \subseteq X$, $S^\perp = \{0\} \iff S^- = X$.

Comment: @HenryW.: You forgot the linear hull since at its core it is: $\langle S\rangle^-=S^{\perp\perp}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the theorem $\ker(T^*) = \text{Range}(T)^\perp$

From here it's simple. A subspace $V$ is dense if and only if $V^\perp=\{0\}$.